# how to filter pivot table to include only the dates from 2019 (multiple selection)

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have vba code to create a pivot table, but I would like to filter the dates in 2019 ("scheduled ship date" part).

```
'create pivot table
Set pvt2 = pvtcache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=startpvt, TableName:="PivotTable2")

pvt2.PivotFields("Scheduled Ship Date").Orientation = xlRowField
With pvt2.PivotFields("Week")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
End With

With pvt2.PivotFields("Item Type")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 2
End With

With pvt2.PivotFields("Quantity Ordered")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
End With

    pvt2.PivotFields("Item Type").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Item Type").CurrentPage = "KIT"

pvt2.PivotFields("Week").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Week").CurrentPage = Cells(2, 2).Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the below code by changing **Pivot Table Name**, **Pivot Table Column**, **Sheet Name** and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim pf As PivotField

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pvtTest").PivotFields("Year")

        pf.ClearAllFilters

        pf.CurrentPage = "2019"

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: But how i can modify this to include the date's in 2019? Because in my data, the dates are starting from 2014.

Comment: My bad..see edited answer. **pf.CurrentPage = "2019"**

Comment: Thank you but i am getting error 1004 "unable to set the currentpage property of the pivotfield class"

Comment: Use **Year** as a filter an try again please.

Comment: I am still getting the error, i even tried to xlDateBetween and put 01/01 and 31/12 but no luck...

Comment: Could you please upload a sample of your dates?

Answer (score 0):

Your "Scheduled Ship Date" contains individual dates and you want to use it as filter.

Then you can either show a `CurrentPage` (which is an individual date only and assumed unwanted), or you switch the visibility of each PivotItem by this:

```
With pvt2.PivotFields("Scheduled Ship Date")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With

With pvt2.PivotFields("Item Type")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 2
End With

With pvt2.PivotFields("Quantity Ordered")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
End With

pvt2.PivotFields("Item Type").ClearAllFilters
pvt2.PivotFields("Item Type").CurrentPage = "KIT"

Dim pi As PivotItem
pvt2.PivotFields("Scheduled Ship Date").ClearAllFilters
pvt2.PivotFields("Scheduled Ship Date").EnableMultiplePageItems = True
For Each pi In pvt2.PivotFields("Scheduled Ship Date").Pivotitems
    If Year(pi.Value) <> 2019 Then pi.Visible = False
Next pi
```

Be aware, that at least one item has to remain visible, so if you don't have a date from 2019, then you`ll get an error.

---

Date filters only work on row fields or column fields (NOT on above solution, where tha date values are a page field). If you would insert "Scheduled Ship Date" as row field, either this can be used:

```
pvt2.PivotFields("Scheduled Ship Date").PivotFilters.Add2 _
    Type:=xlDateThisYear
```

or following:

```
pvt2.PivotFields("Scheduled Ship Date").PivotFilters.Add2 _
    Type:=xlDateBetween, _
    Value1:="01.01.2019", _
    Value2:="31.12.2019", _
    WholeDayFilter:=True
```

Comment: Did you give my answer a try? If it works fine for you, please consider to mark it as answer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). If not, don't hesitate to comment below it.